# path defined in routes file is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

ORIGINAL POST:

I'm probably defining my route incorrectly but I'm following along with [this example](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple).
I've defined my routes like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :distributions do
    resources :workflows do
      collection do
        post :edit_multiple
        put :update_multiple
      end
    end
  end
end
```

obviously there are a bunch of other things within in the admin namespace and I wanted my distributions to belong to the admin namespace and workflows inside of that.

however when I do this:

```
<%= form_tag admin_edit_multiple_distributions_workflows_path do %>
```

or this:

```
<%= form_tag admin_distributions_edit_multiple_workflows_path do %>
```

I get an undefined method or variable error:

```
undefined local variable or method `admin_distributions_edit_multiple_workflows_path' for #<#<Class:0x12c2b2320>:0x12c29dfd8>
```

what'd I do wrong?

Comment: what is the output from 'rake routes'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `edit_multiple` or `update_multiple` in front, like so:

```
edit_multiple_admin_distributions_workflows_path

update_multiple_admin_distributions_workflows_path
```

But, as Nick already mentioned in his comment, `rake routes` should give you the answer anyway.